# MediaWiki upgrade breaks File prefix but legacy Image works

Tags: image, mediawiki

Did a MediaWiki upgrade from 1.15.1 to 1.20.2 by following the simple update [instructions](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aUpgrading#Can_my_wiki_stay_online_while_it_is_upgrading.3F) (basically a new installation, copying over the old LocalSettings.php, update script and copying over images).  Weird thing now is that all of the File: prefixes don't work.  Instead the internal links to images is a "file:name of image" URL rather than "http://mediawiki address/index.php/File:name of image".

Anybody else getting this.  Assuming it is something wrong with the old LocalSettings.php.

Ran the refreshLinks and refreshImageMetadata maintenance scripts without fixing the problem.

Comment: Can you give us a link to your wiki? Or at least tell us what extensions you're using, and show any parts of your LocalSettings.php that might have something to do with namespaces or URLs? In particular, have you changed anything in [`$wgUrlProtocols`](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgUrlProtocols), or do you have any parser extensions, such as [FileLink](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:FileLink), that might interfere with link parsing?

Comment: From the versions page I got SyntaxHighlight as a Parser Extension otherwise just the WikiEditor/MWSearch (for lucene) active.  Noticed that I have a wgUrlProtocols settings of "file:" which isn't part of the 1.20 [defaults](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgUrlProtocols).  Can this mess stuff up?

Comment: Yes, that's likely what's triggering it. You could try changing the URL prefix to `file://` (with the slashes) and see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the comments, you wrote that you have `file:` added to [`$wgUrlProtocols`](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3a%24wgUrlProtocols).  This is very likely what's triggering the problem.

It looks like something has changed in the parser between MW 1.15 and 1.20 so that it's now parsing `file:whatever` as an external link (since it matches the `file:` prefix you've defined in `$wgUrlProtocols`) even if it's inside square brackets.

The obvious workaround would be to change the `$wgUrlProtocols` entry from `file:` to `file://` so that it will only match if the slashes are there (as they should be, according to standard file: URL syntax).  Since your on-wiki filenames are, presumably, very unlikely to begin with double slashes, they should not match this more specific prefix.

That said, this could still be considered a bug in MediaWiki.  You may want to [file a bug report about it](https://bugzilla.wikimedia.org/), if there isn't one yet.
(Edit: Looks like [Mark A. Hershberger filed one already.](https://bugzilla.wikimedia.org/show_bug.cgi?id=44011))

Comment: Was exactly the problem and your workaround of the file:// is perfect.  Thanks!